# Zend framework controller filenames containing "init"?

Tags: zend-framework

Zend framework: what is the significance of controller filenames that have "init" in them? I have 3 files that seems to have exactly the same code, named:

TestController_init.php
TestController.init.php
TestController.php

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should have onlu one `TestController.php` that contains all behaviours that this controller should have (`init()` method, etc).

Could you pase the content of 2 other files ?

Comment: pase? they have a lot of code in them but it's well possible they are not being used at all. cant talk to the original developer to find out. assuming I just need the file without init.

Comment: I mean 'paste'.

However I never met `*Controller_init.php` or `*Controller.init.php` convenction.  I'm sure that it is only this developer own idea to separate some controller initializations and controller's proper action methods.

You should look into bootstrap, `Controller_Action`, `Frontcontroller` layers for calling init files.

Comment: I guess you got some "DIY" code. Zend never had controller files with init in them.